# Проблема c кодировкой после сборки приложения

Tags: java, swing, jar

Здравствуйте,сделал приложение,в котором несколько окошек `JFrame` с русским текстом,после того как упаковал в jar файл и при открытии(без IDE) в Windows7 весь текст в иероглифах.
что в данном случае требуется сделать?

Comment: Попробуй стартануть jar-файл так: java -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -jar jarFileName.jar

Comment: @МихаилКетов нет,по прежнему иероглифы

Comment: нужно перевести `encoding` в `UTF-8` (пересохранить как `UTF-8`)

Comment: @fonjeekay а как это сделать?

Comment: Это зависит от среды в которой вы создавали. То есть даже если писалось всё через блокнот, и компилировалось через командную строку, если я правильно понял, то в блокноте открыть файл содержащий код пересохранить с `UTF-8` ( encoding это кодировка которую можно выставить при сохранении, это зависити от блокнота и от ОС)  и еще раз скомпилировать. Уточните программы которые вы используете, чтобы можно было ответить вам более конкретно...

Comment: Рекомендую все таки использовать IDE для JFrame и свинга. Подойдет и `eclipse` и `netbeans`

Comment: @fonjeekay нет,создавалось всё в еклипсе,по умолчанию кодировка там utf-8.когда я там запускал,всё работает хорошо,но после того как я создал jar файл(с помощью maven) при открытии jar на рабочем столе русский текст отображается не корректно

Comment: @user238409 http://vindavoz.ru/win_obwee/411-krakozyabry-vmesto-russkih-bukv.html такое пробовали ?

Comment: @fonjeekay спасибо большое,щас буду разбираться